# Flashing feedback message in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to flash feedback messages like *"An entry has been created successfully"* or *"You don't have enough permissions to access this item"*.

I want to avoid embedding these messages straight into views, because they can re-appear, for example, when a user navigates back to the previous page with his browser.

To solve this problem, I have a **javascript function** that acts like following:

```js
(showFlashMessage(){
    // 1. make an ajax request
    // 2. retrieve a flash message (if any)
    // 3. display the message
})();
```

This way, the problem of the reappearance of the flash messages is solved. However, by the time the request is made, the flash message has already disappeared. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Im pretty sure the ajax counts as a second request, the flash message only works for the first one (ie when the page loads).

Comment: @Severian That's what I think also. Is there a way to solve this problem? I want to avoid using `Session::put()`

Comment: @Alexander Lomia: For that, i will suggest you to use sweet alert. Please prefer this: [https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert]. It is better than flash messages.:)

Comment: @HirenGohel Thanks, Hiren, but I'm already using them. The problem can only be solved on the server side

Comment: @Alexander Lomia: Oops! so you need to solve it on client side? The problem with client side using sweet-alert??

Comment: @HirenGohel no, it's not solvable on the client side. I need to solve the problem on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to solve the problem on the server side** you can make use of the Session facade like so:

In your controller:

```
function create() {
    if(Gate::allows('createAccess')) {
        Session::flash('error', 'You don't have enough permissions to access this item!');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    // Create the model or perform any other logic

    Session::flash('success', 'An entity has been created successfully!');

    return view('entities.show');
}
```

Then you can have a partial named message.blade.php which is included in your entities.show view:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

If you want to solve the problem on the client side you can call your message function (for example sweet alert message) in the success callback when the request has been completed successfully:

```
function showMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-url',
        data: {
            // Your data here
        },
        success: function() {
            // Show success message
        },
        error: function() {
            // Show error message
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The *problem with the first approach* is, that when html gets generated, the message gets generated and is "bound" to that html. So when a user navigates back to the flashed view, it will always show the flash message. *The problem with the second approach* is when ajax call reaches the action, it's counted as a second request, so the *Session::flash storage is cleared*.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping it simple and call the inbuilt `flash()` method in your controller:

```
flash()->error('We encountered an error whilst doing something');
return redirect('path') //action(), back(), etc;
```

By my understanding, Laravel handles these flash messages in the session and they persist only for the next page view before being removed. If you want to reuse a specific message or combination of message type and content, consider storing this in either a DB table or in `helper.php`

Another option is to pull in the `Laracasts/Flash/Flash` package

Comment: Again, the problem is when I try to retrieve the flashed message via ajax call, because it's counted as a second request, so the flash message is no longer there.